# Looking for a $2\times2$ real matrix $A$ with $Ax$ a contraction for the supremum norm, and not a contraction for the one norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contraction-operator

I am looking for a $2\times2$ real matrix $A$, such that 
$ x\longmapsto Ax $ is a contraction considering  $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and a noncontraction considering $\|\cdot\|_1$.

I have now idea how to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: You must have *some* idea. Try writing out the conditions on $A$ explicitly and see where that leads.

Comment: I know the definitions, but they are of no use for me now. And still now idea where to start

Comment: Write out the formulas that result from the two conditions, with the elements of $A$ listed explicitly.

Comment: Matrix(a,b,c,d). The sup Norm would be max(a+b, c+d), assuming the numbers are positive, the 1Norm would be max(a+c,b+d). Is that correct?Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can take for instance
$$
A=\frac17\,\begin{bmatrix} 3&4\\ 3&4\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then 
$$
\|Ax\|_\infty=\left|\frac{3x_1+4x_2}7\right|\leq\frac{3\|x\|_\infty+4\|x\|_\infty}7\leq \|x\|_\infty.
$$
So $A$ is a contraction for $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

And
$$
\|Ax\|_1=2\left|\frac{3x_1+4x_2}7\right|.
$$
So if $x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, we have $\|x\|_1=1$ and $\|Ax\|_1=\frac87$.

Comment: Dear Martin, please helfp me with that:
$\|Ax\|_\infty=\frac{3x_1+4x_2}4\leq\frac{3\|x\|_\infty+4\|x\|_\infty}4=\|x\|_\infty.$
Why is (3+4)/4=1?
Thank you

Comment: Yes, that made no sense. I have corrected the example just a bit.

Comment: thank you. Now it makes more sense